# How to prevent turbolinks from clearing form input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

We have a Rails 4 app which has turbolinks on by default. An odd behavior that we're seeing is after we submit a form, then click the Back button, turbolinks clears all the previous page's form input. If we disable turbolinks this problem goes away and the form is filled out as expected.

Would anyone know a way to preserve said form input without disabling turbolinks?

Comment: Does it help if you use the jquery-turbolinks gem? Read here, about how to install: https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks#usage

Comment: @AWM Thanks, we tried that, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? When we go back to the form, it seems to be populated with the input params submitted not the last time, but the time before- this is completely unacceptable and confusing.